# how to correctly do logical row filtering in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table and I want to filter based on multiple condition for example my table is:

```
   Old   New

0  '1'    '2'
1  '2'    '2'
2  '2'    '3'
3  '2'    '1'
4  '2'    'C'
5  '3'    '2'
```

I want to select all the rows that had an old value of 2 and a new value other than 1 or 2. The code I have is

```
category_2_improvement = clean_df[(clean_df.old == '2') & (clean_df.new!= '1' or clean_df.new != '2')]
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Not sure if I have to use all or any and where I should put it. In general can some explain the concept? New to pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `or` is probably causing the error here, try:

```
category_2_improvement = clean_df[(clean_df.old == '2')\
& ((clean_df.new!= '1') | (clean_df.new != '2'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query method:

```
category_2_improvement = df.query("Old == '2' and New != '1' and New != '2'")
```

BTW, there is an excellent Pandas tutorial from A.Geron: 
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/tools_pandas.ipynb